# Cosets and Equivalence Relations

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations

Today in math my professor was talking about equivalence relations and modulo. Then he said something about cosets, and I don't understand the relation. I read that a coset was a subgroup with all if it's elements added with another element of the group. And I guess equivalence relations for subgroups, at least the integers mod some number?
My main question is how are cosets and equivalence relations related?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1014784/589

Answer (score 4):

The *right* cosets of a subgroup $H\le G$ are precisely the classes of the equivalence relation "right modulo $H$" in $G$ defined by:
$$x\sim_R y\iff xy^{-1}\in H$$
In fact, $xy^{-1}\in H\iff x\in Hy$, and hence:
$$[y]_R=Hy$$
Note that the *left* cosets are instead the classes of the equivalence relation "left modulo $H$":
$$x\sim_L y\iff y^{-1}x\in H$$
namely:
$$[y]_L=yH$$
In an abelian group the two equivalence relations are actually one and the same, as $xy^{-1}=y^{-1}x$ for every $x,y\in G$. In particular, for $G=(\Bbb Z,+)$ and $H=n\Bbb Z$ (for any $n\in\Bbb N$), the cosets are the sets:
\begin{alignat}{1}
[m]_n&=m+n\Bbb Z \\
&=\{m+kn\mid k\in \Bbb Z\} \\
\end{alignat}
for any $m\in \Bbb Z$. Note that: $$[m]_n=[m+n]_n$$

Answer (score 0):

Cosets and equivalences relations are not related, except inasmuch as you can define an equivalence relation fairly naturally on the cosets of some subgroup of a group.

For example, taking the group $G = (\mathbb{Z}, +)$, and its subgroup $(3\mathbb{Z},+)$ gives you an infinite number of cosets $(\dots,-1 + 3\mathbb{Z}, 0 + 3\mathbb{Z}, 1 + 3\mathbb{Z}, 2 + 3\mathbb{Z}, 4 + 3\mathbb{Z},\dots)$. However, as $1 + 3\mathbb{Z}$ and $4 + 3\mathbb{Z}$ define the same sets, they are equivalent, both being the set of numbers equivalent to $1$ mod $3$.

Comment: What is $1 +$ $3 \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $1+3\mathbb{Z}=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}|x=3k+1,k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$